# XPath search child

Tags: xml, xpath, simplexml

I have an XML that goes like this:

```
<document>
  <FileDetails>
  </FileDetails>
  <Clients>
    <Client>
      <ClientDetails>
        <clientName>xxxx</clientName>
        <clientContact>xxxx</clientContact>
        <clientContactEmail>info@xxxx.com</clientContactEmail>
        <clientTelephone>xxxx</clientTelephone>
      </ClientDetails>
      <properties>
        <Property>
          <propertyid>Foo1</propertyid>
          <category>Commercial</category>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <propertyid>Foo2</propertyid>
          <category>Residential</category>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <propertyid>Foo3</propertyid>
          <category>Residential</category>
        </Property>
      </properties>
    </Client>
  </Clients>
</document>
```

How do I retrieve the Property which has a child named "propertyid" whose value is Foo1?

Comment: //Property/propertyid[contains(.,'Foo1')] is my best shot, but it returns just the propertyid child. I need the whole Property

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with xpath only for html docs, not sure if the same would apply for xml.

I would something along the lines of:

```
//Property/propertyid[@text() = "Foo1"]/..
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ancestor**.

```
//Property/propertyid[text()='Foo1']/ancestor::Property
```

This will give you the nearest ancestor Property element.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach is the following:

```
 //Property[propertyid = 'Foo1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use predicates at any level in an xpath expression

```
//Property[propertyid = 'Foo1']
```

will give you elements that have a propertyid child whose value is exactly `Foo1`, if you want a substring match you can use a nested predicate

```
//Property[propertyid[contains(., 'Foo1')]]
```

If you know that each `Property` will have *exactly one* `propertyid` child then you can use the simpler

```
//Property[contains(propertyid, 'Foo1')]
```

but for other similar cases where there might be more than one of the child element, the nested approach with `contains(., '...')` is safer (in particular, `contains(x, '...')` checks only the first `x` child, whereas `x[contains(., '...')]` checks them all).